# Mapping array of object first element to another object using mapstructs

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to map an array of objects, specifically the first element (array[0]), from one class to another using MapStruct.  Currently getting error like “people[0] not in the property of source did you mean people”.

```
` public class Source {
   private Person[] people;

   // Getter and Setter
    }
```

//     Destination class
public class Destination {
private Person person;

```
   // Getter and Setter
  }
```

// Person class (assuming it's a separate class)
public class Person {
private String name;

```
// Getter and Setter
 }
```

// Mapper interface
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
MyMapper INSTANCE =       Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

```
@Mapping(source = "people[0]", target = "person")
Destination mapToDestination(Source source);`
```

}

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct doesn't directly support mapping elements of an array by their index in the way you're attempting to do it. Instead, you can create a custom method in your mapper interface to manually perform this mapping.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "person", source = "people")
    Destination mapToDestination(Source source);

    default Person mapPersonFromArray(Person[] people) {
        return (people != null && people.length > 0) ? people[0] : null;
    }
}
```

In this example:

@Mapping(target = "person", source = "people"): This tells MapStruct to use the mapPersonFromArray method to map the people field to the person field.

default Person mapPersonFromArray(Person[] people): This is a custom method that manually performs the mapping. It checks if the array is not null and has at least one element, and if so, it returns the first element; otherwise, it returns null.

Remember to adjust the Person class and the mapper interface according to your actual classes and requirements.

This way, MapStruct will use the custom method to map the first element of the people array to the person field in the Destination class.